# SELECT all rows where same value in column 'a' and 'b' but do not the same value 'c'

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table:

```
ID  | a | b | c |
1     1   1   1
2     1   1   2
3     2   2   1
4     1   2   3
5     2   2   1
```

I need to select all duplicate rows where I have the same value in column 'a' and 'b' but do not have the same in 'c'

So in this case I should get rows with ID=1,2

I can use GROUP BY to group value 'a' and 'b' and then select it if it count more than 1, but I dont know how to include this check about column 'c'.

Could you help me, please.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: I want to get whole row.

Comment: Which row? If you specify the expected result it's much easier to understand exactly what you want.

Comment: So in this case I should get rows with ID=1,2

Comment: That's _describing_ the result, not _specifying_. Do just like you did with the sample data, a properly formatted table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.a = t.a and t2.b = t.b and
                    t2.c <> t.c
             );
```

If you just wanted the `a`/`b` values, then you could use aggregation:

```
select a, b
from t
group by a, b
having min(c) <> max(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use :

```
select t1.id from table t1 cross join table t2 
where s1.a=s2.a and s1.b=s2.b and s1.c!=s2.c
```